# Firefox: Transition placeholder opacity

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I wanted to make input placeholder fade smoothly on focus using transition, but can't get it to work in FF.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="some cool text"/>

input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
    opacity: 0.1;
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
    opacity: 1;
}
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     opacity: 0.1;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/de9aE/5/)

Works fine in Chrome, but not in FF.
The placeholder changes opacity on focus as intended, but 1s transition doesn't appear. It also definitely doesn't work in IE

EDIT: Apparently its a bug in the latest version of FF (20.0.1)

Answer (score 2):

How about doing it like this? Instead of using `opacity`, switch the color shades

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/de9aE/16/)

```
<input type="text" placeholder="some cool text"/>

input[type=text]:-moz-placeholder {
color: #000;
transition: color 1s;
}

input[type=text]:focus:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #aaa;
}

input[type=text]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #000;
    transition: color 1s;
}

input[type=text]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #aaa;
}
```

Certainly you can use `opacity` if you want but you can see the result yourself and decide what's better for you, [**opacity demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/de9aE/15/)

> Note: Use `::-moz-placeholder` to support +19 Ver

Comment: @btevfik Just add the proprietary properties you want, I updated, and the question focused `firefox` but anyways I added webkit support too

Comment: actually this doesn't work in firefox either. i just realized he was asking on firefox. but what he posted didnt work on chrome either. my answer doesnt work on ff either.

Comment: hmm. idk whats going on. i am testing on mac if that makes any difference.

Comment: @btevfik For supporting firefox +19, you need to use `::` i.e `::-moz-placeholder`

Comment: @skyisred Did this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/de9aE/17/ for color and http://jsfiddle.net/de9aE/18/ for opacity

Comment: No, in both it changes opacity, but without transition. (Got latest FF version)

Comment: all right..i might be creeping into this conversation, but do windows and max FF differ ?

Comment: @AdityaSaxena Nope...and skyisred I don't know what's wrong here but works completely for me

Comment: checked it on mac, doesn't work either. Alien, what version of FF do you have?

Comment: i'm using 20.0.1, so it must be a new bug

Comment: @skyisred it is working, install the older version and check it out

Comment: Using FF 54 and this does not work, opacity changes with no transition

Answer (score 1):

Transition on ::placeholder should not be supported by any browser as it is not defined by specification, so that can be considered non-standard behavior. The fact that Firefox does not support it is correct behavior:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1115623

By specification, only ::after and ::before pseudo-elements have transition property enabled. All other pseudo-elements don't.

Here's more: [Why is a transition property on the placeholder pseudoelement valid in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246282/why-is-a-transition-property-on-the-placeholder-pseudoelement-valid-in-chrome)