# Firefox + Edge input placeholder opacity transition

Tags: css, sass, placeholder

I have tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381895/firefox-transition-placeholder-opacity) and the other duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547549/css3-placeholder-hover-transition-not-working-in-firefox?noredirect=1&lq=1), but those questions are 4 years old and the solutions do not work on newer versions of Firefox. Also, the bug linked in the latter has status: VERIFIED FIXED.

I have tried using only the transition prefix matching the placeholder prefix along with the transition fallback with no luck. ex:

```
&::-moz-placeholder {
    -moz-transition: $transition;
    transition: $transition;
}
```

What's below works on chrome but not Firefox or Edge. The opacity changes fine but there is no transition. Am I missing something to support both Firefox and Edge placeholder transitions?

```
@mixin transition($transition...) {
    -webkit-transition: $transition;
    -moz-transition: $transition;
    -o-transition: $transition;
    transition: $transition;
}

@mixin placeholderOpacity($opacity) {
    &:-moz-placeholder {opacity: $opacity}
    &:-ms-input-placeholder  {opacity: $opacity}
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder {opacity: $opacity}
    &::-moz-placeholder {opacity: $opacity}
    &::placeholder  {opacity: $opacity}
}

@mixin placeholderTransition($transition) {
    &:-moz-placeholder {@include transition($transition);}
    &:-ms-input-placeholder  {@include transition($transition);}
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder {@include transition($transition);}
    &::-moz-placeholder {@include transition($transition);}
    &::placeholder  {@include transition($transition);}
}

input {
    @include placeholderOpacity(0);
    @include placeholderTransition(opacity 500ms ease-in-out);
}

input:focus {
    @include placeholderOpacity(1);
}
```

Comment: For a cross browser solution, maybe this answer of mine would be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333727/simulation-of-a-placeholder/44333787#44333787

Comment: umm, my answers :) I just tried on the latest Firefox and yes, it fails.. can you give me a day to solve it? I'll see if I can find an alternative way to animate the placeholders.

Comment: @LGSon Thank you, I am not opposed to javascript solutions if it's not possible with CSS.

Comment: Well, the script has actually nothing to do with the animation itself, it fixes an issue the input element has, where when one adds a value to an input, you can't detect using the CSS `input:not([value=""])` if there is a value or not, as the selector check the `input`s attribute `value`, which is not the same as what you enter in the field

Comment: @LGSon I see, I just took a quick peek before. I already have a label effect like the one listed in your answer but now I'm trying to transition the placeholder in to view while the label is transitioning to the top. Since I already have something very similar to your answer it would be easy to do the same thing on another element. In my specific case it would require a little more JS, so I would prefer a pure CSS solution if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no real cross browser solution to style and animate placeholder's, I decided to post an updated version from another answer of mine, where this one having both a *label*, a *placeholder* and a *required* asterisk.

I have added a tiny script with one purpose only, to replicate what is written in an `input` field to its *attribute* `value`.

With that, one can then use CSS alone for the actual styling and animations, by simply use the attribute selector `[attribute="value"]` (in the way I think most users expect it to be used)

```js
(function(pls) {
  /* run this script when page loaded */
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    /* find and iterate all "input placeholder" elements */
    pls = document.querySelectorAll('.placeholder input');
    for (var i = 0; i < pls.length; i++) {
      /* attach a handler to replicate input value */
      pls[i].addEventListener('input', function() {
        this.setAttribute('value', this.value);
      })
    }
  })
})();
```

```css
.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.placeholder + .placeholder {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.placeholder label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  top: calc(50.5% + 7.5px);
  transform: translateY(-50.5%);
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
.placeholder label::before,
.placeholder label span {  
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: top .5s;
}

/* the label text + asterisk */
.placeholder input + label::before {
  content: attr(data-text) ' '; 
  color: black;
}
.placeholder label span {
  color: red;
}
.placeholder input:not([required]) + label span {
  display: none;
}
.placeholder input:not([value=""]) + label::before,
.placeholder input:focus + label::before,
.placeholder input:not([value=""]) + label span,
.placeholder input:focus + label span {
  top: -22px;
}

/* the placeholder text */
.placeholder input + label::after {
  content: attr(data-placeholder); 
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  color: gray;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s .2s;
}
.placeholder input:focus + label::after {
  opacity:  1;
}
.placeholder input:not([value=""]) + label::after {
  opacity:  0;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="placeholder">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="">
  <label data-text="Name" data-placeholder="Add your name"><span>*</span></label>
</div>
<div class="placeholder">
  <input type="text" name="mail" value="" required>
  <label data-text="Email" data-placeholder="Add your email address"><span>*</span></label>
</div>
```