# Why is a transition property on the placeholder pseudoelement valid in Chrome?

Tags: css, css-transitions, placeholder

I was goofing around with the `::placeholder` pseudoelement on Codepen (Chrome 59.0.3071) when I noticed something odd. (please see my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ct6zkaw/))

In brief, this CSS should not enable a transition of the `::placeholder` color over 2s:

```
input::placeholder {color:red;transition:2s;}
input:hover::placeholder {color:green}
```

Using Firefox, there is no color transition over a 2 second interval on hover  (this appears to be correct according to [this section](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#propdef-transition) of a W3C spec and [this section](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#placeholder-pseudo) of a different one - follow the thread to the `::first-line` pseudo-element), but instead there is an immediate color transition to green;

However, the same JSFiddle using Chrome *does* show a `::placeholder` color transition over a period of 2 seconds, which according to the specs, appears to be incorrect.

*Is this a bug in this version of Chrome (and if so, is it being addressed?) or is this an indictment of my lack of understanding of CSS?*

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/09gc1wvd/ I was able to get FF 54 to do transitions using brackets rather than `::`, so maybe the specs are wrong?

Comment: @SamuelCook these are completely different things! With brackets notation, you select the originating element, not a pseudo element. The selector `input:hover[placeholder]` means "the `input` element that is hovered *and* has a `placeholder` attribute". So your example doesn't prove that the specs are wrong w.r.t. _placeholder pseudo element_ (although they probably are:).

Comment: Interestingly, the spec claims `::placeholder` has all the properties of `::first-line`, but when you do the same experiment on `::first-line`, both FF and Chrome have no transition.  See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Auroratide/fr017m9L/1/) and observe the difference.  Reading the spec carefully, it is unclear to me whether the set of `::placeholder` properties is a _superset_ of the `::first-line` properties or exactly equal.

Comment: @Auroratide, though it may not be the "Accepted Answer", this comment IMO is worth being an Answer

Answer (score 4):

> Currently, it seems that Gecko's and Webkit's implementations are very
>   similar. The set of allowed rules are slightly different and the
>   default styling isn't the same but those are clearly solvable issues.

**--** From http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Jan/0283.html

> Non-standard This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
>   track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
>   work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

**--** From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::-moz-placeholder

> Only the subset of CSS properties that apply to the `::first-line`
>   pseudo-element can be used in a rule using `::placeholder` in its
>   selector.

**--** From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder

But apparently both Chrome and Firefox apply no transitions for `::first-line`, as is evident through [this JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atif_hassan/dvmpno1y/) I made.

Also while I was searching on the net for answers, I found that the `transition` property for `::placeholder` was working in an older version of Firefox with vendor prefixes which simply reconfirms the line from spec,

> behaviour may change in the future.

Here's the code for the JSfiddle.

```css
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
  transition: 2s;
}

input:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: green
}

p::first-line {
  color: red;
  transition: 2s;
}

p:hover::first-line {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Sup">
<br />

<p style="display:inline-block">This is the first line.</br> Check it out</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find it in the w3c docs. 
It looks like it used to work in some older Firefox versions.

A workaround with css could be:

```
input[placeholder]{color:red; transition:color 2.1s;}
input:focus[placeholder]{color:blue}
```

Which works in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to convey here. The question cites the latest version of the spec as saying that transitions only apply to ::before and ::after pseudo-elements, not the ::placeholder pseudo-element, and the older draft that you cite - and I don't know why you've chosen an older draft - *also* says that it only applies to elements and ":before and :after pseudo elements". You seem to be trying to disprove the claim in the question, but the source you cite *confirms* that it has been, in fact, this way for much longer.

Comment: You're actually right, I misread the documentation. I will edit my answer, leave the workaround here.

Comment: The workaround is to simply not specify transitions on the ::placeholder pseudo-element. But that's not what the question is asking.